# Not able to make a own method to use Explicit Wait method of selenium

Tags: java, selenium, wait

```
class Test{     
public static WebDriver driver=null;
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.navigate().to("http://www.w3schools.com/");
    Test.explicitWait("invisibilityOfElementLocated","xpath","//*[text()='LEARN HTML']");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='HTML REFERENCE']")).click();
    }

public static void explicitWait(String expectedConditionsMethod,String byMethod,String locator) throws Exception{
    WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    Method by=By.class.getMethod(byMethod, String.class);
    Object bymethod=by.invoke(null, locator);
    Method expectedConditions=ExpectedConditions.class.getMethod(expectedConditionsMethod, By.class);
    wait.until((Predicate<WebDriver>) expectedConditions.invoke(null, bymethod));
}

}
```

I want to make a explicit wait method which can be called directly as shown above but i am not able to do it, please help.
Getting error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$18 cannot be cast to com.google.common.base.Predicate
    at roughWork.Test.explicitWait(Test.java:110)
    at roughWork.Test.main(Test.java:29)
"
in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your implementation (it appears) is that your explicitWait method will not work if you pass a expected condition method that does not return a WebDriver object.

In your case, when you call `invisibilityOfElementLocated`, [that method returns a Boolean](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#invisibilityOfElementLocated-org.openqa.selenium.By-) , not a WebDriver.   Other methods in ExpectedConditions class return a List of WebElements.  So, you would need 3 different explicit wait methods to handle the 3 different return predicate types.

I would suggest writing methods for your tests that only take a locator or a WebElement as a single argument instead of trying to `double-engineer it` to pass String names of methods in the ExpectedConditions class.  Your asking for trouble anyways if the implementation of that class changes.